# Case insensitive key name match , Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I have a mongoose schema

```
    let entrySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        "Request ID": {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        "Assigned To": String,
        "Last Modified By": String,
        "Status": String,
    },
    { timestamps: true, strict: false }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('entry', entrySchema);
```

Now, I cant do `scmea_obj.find({status: 'new'})`. Here status is lower case. How can I make .find case insensitive for **keys**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression like as bellow query

```
scmea_obj.find({status : new RegExp('^new$', "i")});
```